# Open Foam User Guide Tutorial

Tags: openfoam

I am trying to follow the Openfoam user guide but I'm stuck at the first tutorial [1](http://www.openfoam.org/docs/user/cavity.php).
In fact, when I try to run the *blockMesh* command (using the administrator account), the following appears:

> Writing polyMesh
>
> --> FOAM FATAL ERROR: 
>   Failed writing polyMesh.
>
> From function blockMesh
>      in file blockMeshApp.C at line 325.
>
> FOAM exiting

I tried to follow instructions given in this thread [2](http://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/openfoam/87129-polymesh-problem.html) but none of the two here proposed can help me.

Any advice?

Thanking you in advance,
Filippo

Comment: You're using the admin account... OK. But are you running it in your home folder? Somewhere else? What is the path where you run `blockMesh`, and what is the full command you run?

Comment: Dear Filippo, welcome to SciComp. The question you're asking is more related to the installation of OpenFOAM itself than to the numerical analysis/algorithms behind it. I think you're better off contacting your local sysadmin or the OpenFOAM community.

Answer (score 1):

I would check if you are in the proper case directory and not in any other directory, such as `$CASE/constant/polyMesh` or something similar. Have you copied the tutorial from `$FOAM_TUTORIALS` to your home directory or somewhere else, where you have proper permissions to read and write? I generally suggest not to use the administrator's account for your daily work.

Hope this helps, otherwise please provide more information (OpenFOAM version, etc.)